# PHP search FULLTEXT escape string from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

here are my data from table `Companies` column `cName`

```
CK'Wang Pte Ltd
Chong Wang Pte Ltd
CK'Studio Pte Ltd
```

here are my query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT cName FROM Companies WHERE MATCH cName AGAINST ('+CK\'Wang Pte Ltd' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

the $result show 2. How can i only MATCH 1 (`CK'Wang Pte Ltd`) instead of 2

Comment: use parameters instead of inline SQL to avoid the need to escape in the first place (and avoid SQL injection)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all of the terms to match in boolean mode, you need to add a + in front of every term. The way the query is interpreted, CK is mandatory, all other terms are optional and will mostly affect the ranking of results.

If you need to build the query from a user request and match all terms, you will need to convert it first.

```
function fulltext_match_all($query)
{
    $final = array();
    foreach (array_filter(preg_split('/[\s\'-]+/', $query)) as $word) {
            $final[] = "+$word";
    }
    $query = implode(' ', $final);
}
```

Your final query would look something like this:

```
SELECT cName FROM Companies WHERE MATCH cName AGAINST ('+CK +Wang +Pte +Ltd' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```